# Confused on how to get javascript prototypes to act kindly with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to refine my javascript skills by working on developing more object oriented javascript code. While I'm fluent in Java OOP syntax and concepts, I'm lost when it comes to javascript.

While the ball initializes fine, I can't figure out how to get the thing to move! If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

The ball is, at least currently, supposed to just bounce off the "walls" of the canvas.

Here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var x=canvas.width/2;//x ball position
var y = canvas.height-30;//y ball posi
var dx=2;
var dy=-2;
var ballRadius = 10;
function Ball(){

}
//draws gameball
Ball.prototype.drawBall=function(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
    this.checkWalls();
    fillStyle="#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
//dynamically draw balls position
Ball.prototype.draw=function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.drawBall();
    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;
    this.checkWalls(x,y,dx,dy);
}
Ball.prototype.refresh=function(){
    setInterval(this.draw(),8);
}

Ball.prototype.checkWalls=function(x,y,dx,dy){

    //reverse direction if ball hits top or bottom
    if(this.y+this.dy> canvas.height-ballRadius || this.y + this.dy <ballRadius){
        this.dy=-dy;
    }
    //reverse direction if ball hits left or right
    if(this.x+this.dx>canvas.width-ballRadius || this.x+this.dx<ballRadius){
        this.dx=-dx;
    }   
}

//instantiate objects
var ball = new Ball();
ball.refresh();
```

Here's the UPDATED: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ch0chi/d6mce9yq/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do like that `setInterval(this.draw(), 8)` your `this.draw()` executed and return undefined but it has to return function which setInterval must be invoke.

Simple way:

```
Ball.prototype.refresh=function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        self.draw();
    },8);
}
```

It is important that `this` is point to itself object so you have to use set local variable `self`

Fast way:

```
Ball.prototype.refresh=function(){
    setInterval(this.draw.bind(this),8);
}
```

`bind` method link `this.draw` to `this` context and return function like in the simple example.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining how bind is working here?
Also, the ball seems to not be "bouncing" off of the walls. Will I have to use bind on the checkWalls function as well?

Comment: @ch0chi The problem is that `setInterval(this.draw(), 8)` will instantly call `this.draw()` and use its return value as the first parameter of `setInterval` which would be `undefined`. You have to pass a function as the first parameter, therefor it has to be `this.draw`. But then you still have to "fix" the value of `this` to let it reference the Ball object. Otherwise it would refer to `window` when the interval executes the function. And that's what [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) accomplishes here.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! No wonder it wouldn't move...

Do I need to apply the same method to the checkWalls method? It seems that the ball will move out of the window.

Comment: your local arguments in `checkWalls`(x, y, dy, dx) conflict with global variables with the same names. And there is no need to use `this.x, this.y, this.dy, this.dx` in your case because it is not using.

Comment: Oh, duh. Works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/d6mce9yq/2/

Been working on canvas recently and this is what I have used.

```
// game loop function
    var loop = function () {
        //update();
        //draw();
    ball.refresh(); 
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
```

Also add this at the top to make it run 60fps :

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( /* function */ callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  );
}();
```

Here is your working walls fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/d6mce9yq/7/

I have changed quite a few things.

Added x,y,dx,dy to the actual ball:

```
function Ball() {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;    
}
```

Then used these values later on (all in fiddle). Your 'checkwalls' function now looks like :

```
Ball.prototype.checkWalls = function(x, y, dx, dy, thisBall) {

  //console.log(thisBall.dx)
  //reverse direction if ball hits top or bottom
  if (this.y > canvas.height - ballRadius || this.y < ballRadius) {
    //this.y-=dy;
    this.dy *= -1;
  }
  //reverse direction if ball hits left or right
  if (this.x > canvas.width - ballRadius || this.x < ballRadius) {
    //this.xdx;
    this.dx *= -1;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `requestAnimFrame !== requestAnimationFrame`; there is no second parameter for [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame); your solution will create 60 new intervals per second; this doesn't fix the problem of the question...

Comment: You're right at the second argument, but the ball moves so this does solve the question ?

Comment: The ball moves because of the actual problem

Comment: @thisOneGuy I appreciate your answer, but it seems to be a little more efficient to use Andreas's answer. Still stuck on how to actually get the ball to bounce off the edges though.